# Iterate through array when item is found end loop but not found call function

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi all I have a question. I have an array that is dynamically populated. In the array there are 2 main types of items. Item with file name that equals 27 characters and the rest are either more or less. I am able to separate the 2 two types. The second list is added to a new array called $usedArray. Those items are then iterated through and the file name is substringed from character 0,6 to be used to compare the enduser's input on the page.
if the item is found in that array it will fire a function to send them a text and a email of the the full file name. my problem is if the item is not found until x iterations, it would fire the not found function x amount of times, and if it's not found at all it does the same thing. If I have 99 items that do not match it fire 99 times.  to stop from firing I left the not found to just printing not found on the screen. I thought of calling the notfound function outside the loop but do not want it to fire if an items is found
This is my code I have so far

```
do{
    if (substr($val,0,6) == $studentID)
    {

        $codeFound = substr($val,22,19);
        print_r($studentID . ' is found <br /> Their code is ' . $codeFound);
        //sendText($phoneNum,$codeFound,$messageMonth);
        //sendEmail($emailInfo,$messageMonth,$codeFound);
        break 1;

    }
    else
    {
        print_r($studentID . " was not found <br />");
    }

} while(list(, $val) = each($usedArray));
```

This is my output

```
166003 was not found
166003 was not found
166003 was not found
166003 is found
Their code is xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: So the problem is - you want to send not found only when iterating over your array found nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a flag to track if you have found something or not:

```
$item_found = false;
do{
    if (substr($val,0,6) == $studentID)
    {

        $codeFound = substr($val,22,19);
        print_r($studentID . ' is found <br /> Their code is ' . $codeFound);
        //sendText($phoneNum,$codeFound,$messageMonth);
        //sendEmail($emailInfo,$messageMonth,$codeFound);

        // item found!
        $item_found = true;

        break 1;
    }
} while(list(, $val) = each($usedArray));

// now check - if `$item_found` is false 
// then you can send your NotFoundEmail
if (!$item_found) {
    sendNotFoundEmail();
}
```